# Dell Inspiron m5030 boots to a black screen with a mouse pointer

Tags: 11.10, boot, dell, inspiron

I have a dell inspiron m5030 and i have successfully installed ubuntu 11.10 64-bit. Whenever I boot with ubuntu it boots to a black screen with the mouse pointer, or the default background with the mouse pointer. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What graphics card do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

When you turn on your pc wait for grub boot menu and hit `e` then look for the line that quotes `quiet splash` or something like that and edit those words to say `acpi=off` then hit ctrl+X

Hope this helps